# Comic - woman in dystopian world

Tags: story-identification, comics

Looking for the title of a comic book series I read circa 1997.

If I remember correctly, it's about a woman who wakes up in a strange place without memory. In one of the later issues I think she finds out it is actually a big spaceship.

Some additional points

- The story involves quite a bit of nudity and violence.
- The comic was in color, I bought it used at a comic book store in Germany (it was in German language) - so it might have been older.
- The protagonist woke up naked and from there on it was a struggle for survival for her, she met mostly people that wanted to kill her or worse. Everyone was just about his own survival.
- Fights involved knives and guns (pistols and shotguns, etc) rather than futuristic weapons. During fights her wardrobe would get torn up, leaving her naked or barely covered again.
- The protagonist was white, in her twenties with brown, shoulder-length curly hair
- The area she was exploring was a series of rooms and hallways, though some were filled with sand or dirt, some were quite big. it could as well have been a post-apocalyptic underground setting, dirty and used up, old with lots of trash lying around.
- She wanted to reach the surface but nobody there knew they were on a spaceship.
- At some point she reaches a metal wall and follows it to a hatch with a window, through which she can see space.
- There were no aliens, just humans.

Comment: I'm very sure you can remember more than that. Have a look through the checklist here to see if there's anything you can add; "[How to ask a good story-ID question"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Was the comic in colour or black & white? Was it British, American or Japanese? Where are you likely to have bought it from? What age was the woman protagonist? What race/ethnicity was the protagonist? Where she woke up, was it futuristic or contemporary? How did she learn that it was a spaceship? Why was there nudity/violence - who was getting nude and why, who was fighting and why? Did the violence involve weapons, rayguns, lasers, swords, etc? Were there any other characters? Were there any aliens or other sci-fi type tropes?

Comment: Much better. I told you you'd remember more :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might it be the "Morbus Gravis" series ?

> "After a series of adventures, Druuna discovers that the City is
>   actually a giant spaceship"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druuna#Morbus_Gravis

Comment: Yes! "Morbus Gravis" is what i was looking for. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy since I started thinking about it this morning. awesome, there are even re-published non-shortened versions on amazon :)